# JavaScript for hiding Dates

Tags: javascript

I've used a JavaScript for hiding concert dates on a website for a client. It works fine. Now I wanted to reuse it for another site and copied it. But now it won't work, and I can't find the error...

The script I'm using is the following and is stored in "js/termine.js":

```
// <![CDATA[
function aktualisieren() {
  if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
  var Datum = new Date();
  var Jahr = Datum.getFullYear().toString();
  var Monat = (Datum.getMonth()+1).toString();
      if (Monat.length == 1) Monat = "0" + Monat;
  var Tag = Datum.getDate().toString();
      if (Tag.length == 1) Tag = "0" + Tag;
  var aktuell = parseInt(Jahr + Monat + Tag);
  var Zeilen = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
      for (var i = 0; i < Zeilen.length; i++) {
  if (Zeilen[i].title) {
      if (parseInt(Zeilen[i].title) < aktuell) Zeilen[i].style.display = "none";
         }
      }
  }
// ]]>
```

In the html-head I'm linking to that file via:

```
<script src="js/termine.js"></script>
```

The dates are stored in "termine.inc", which I'm including via php:

```
<div id="termine"><?php include("includes/termine.inc"); ?></div>
```

Can somebody give me a hint, what I'm missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly do you expect it to do?

Comment: You're including the css file, with php, in the document, but giving a link to an external file..?

Comment: 1) You could process the file `termine.inc` in PHP on the server and only send the required data to the client. 2) The problem might be in the contents of that file.

Comment: You are checking that `Zeilen[i].title` exists but in your `<div>` there isn't any title

Comment: @richieahb The script hides the concert-dates of the past (f.e. yesterday and last week or so), so I can delete the dates, when I have the time.

Comment: @sergiomse The title for the script is in the `termine.inc`: f.e. `<div title="20140921">...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it seems that you are missing a tag name

```
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
```

If you are trying to get all tag i suggest you try

```
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName("*")) return;
```

Comment: Unfortunately your tipp didn't do the trick :/ The script works just fine on another site: www.reinhold-friedich.de... and I can't find the problem on my new site...

Comment: I tried accessing the site now to see if I can see anything but it seems to be offline

Comment: Sorry @Ernie, there's a typo: www.reinhold-friedrich.de That's the side the script is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I am THAT stupid. Forgot the onload-action in the body... sorry, for wasting your time!!!